# SQL Query to get SUM depending on column values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a following table

```
InvoiceNum | CheckAmt | CheckNum | 
----------------------------------
1234       |10.00     |1244      |
2346       |11.00     |1244      |
4176       |12.00     |1244      |
5213       |15.00     |1673      |
```

Above table represent a payment by a customer. A customer can have multiple invoice and they can pay by single check.

For example first three rows are paid by same check. So I would like something like below after query is applied

```
InvoiceNum       | CheckAmt | CheckNum |
----------------------------------------
1234, 2346, 4176 | 33.00    | 1244     |
5213             | 15.00    | 1673     |
```

Is it posible?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for your case:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(`InvoiceNum`), SUM(`CheckAmt`) FROM `YourTable` GROUP BY `CheckNum`
```

Comment: I think I found the solution using andreah help. Query should be like following                                               SELECT SUM(CheckAmount1), CheckDate1, GROUP_CONCAT(CheckNumber1, InvoiceNum)
       FROM Pickupsales GROUP BY CheckNum1;

Comment: Sorry I forget `GROUP BY`. It's late :-)

Comment: @Santoshshreshta I'm afraid I think it's fair to say that there is no problem in sql for which that might be a valid solution

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html):

Use `GROUP BY` to group the rows by check number.
Use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to concatenate grouped invoice numbers with a comma `SEPARATOR`.
Use [`SUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) to sum grouped check amounts.

Here's an example:

```sql
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(`InvoiceNum` SEPARATOR ', ') AS `InvoiceNum`,
    SUM(`CheckAmt`) AS `CheckAmt`,
    `checkNum`
FROM
    `yourTable`
GROUP BY
    `checkNum`
```